# How do I select all pseudo-class child elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Is there a more concise way of writing this CSS?

```
.vertical > a:link,
.vertical > a:visited,
.vertical > a:hover,
.vertical > a:active
{color:blue;}
```

I am just looking to select all the **a** pseudoclasses inside a **.vertical** div and set all to blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
.vertical > a
```

It is common to have a stronger rule that overrides it though, so you may have to use the pseudo-classes to create an equally strong rule, or use `!important` or other selectors to see the effects.

Comment: Thanks! That is precisely the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is as basic as you can make it for all `a` tags within a `.vertical` class element:

```
.vertical a {color:blue;}
```

or:

```
.vertical > a {color:blue;}
```

for `a` tags that are immediate children of the .vertical class.